# Python Lambda function call with list and output processed list

Tags: python-3.x, lambda

The question is `odds([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])` the output must be `[1, 3, 5]`. I know its simple in list comprehension, or a small function.

````
def odds(l):
    r = []
    for n in l:
        if n % 2 == 1:
            r.append(n)
    return(r)```

or


    def odds(l):
        return [n for n in l if n % 2 == 1]

but i need the output using lambda function shown below

    odds = lambda :
````

Answer (score 2):

`odds = lambda l: [x for x in l if x % 2 == 1]`

Without list expression:

`odds = lambda l: list(filter(lambda x:x%2==1, l))`

But list expressions are the more pythonic solution always.

Comment: you are still using list comprehension, no list comprehension must be used.

Comment: you didn't wrote that. But well, then I would say: `odds = lambda l: list(filter(lambda x:x%2==1, l))`

Answer (score 1):

This stores a `lambda` function object in `ans`.

```
ans = lambda l: [i for i in l if i&1 == 1]
```

To use the function:

```
ans([1,2,3,4,5,6,7])
```

```
Output:

[1, 3, 5, 7]
```

Comment: you are still using list comprehension, no list comprehension must be used.

Answer (score 0):

```
odds = lambda _: list(filter(None, map(lambda x: x if x % 2 == 1 else None, _)))
```

Without using list comprehension I think there is no simpler way.